# Turning a JFrame black when opening another window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, jframe

I wan't to make my main JFrame become darken when the focus is on another window.
This is an example from the game Football Manager 2012. First the main window is selected and it looks like it should, then when it is loading, it turns darker and unselectable. I wan't to have this effects on my own application, but im not really sure how, not even sure what to google?

Im guessing its a JWindow that appears and the JFram becomes unselectable in the background. I'm planing to use it on a help-window in my application, that is a JWindow right now.

[image]
[image]

Comment: May be you are talking about Lightbox effect. If yes then [this](http://harryjoy.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/lightbox-jar/) can help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Andrew Thompson has the right idea, only it's easier to use the glass pane feature of your frame's `JRootPane`. Here's some working code: In your frame class, invoke

```
getRootPane().setGlassPane(new JComponent() {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
});
```

Then, to show the "curtain", invoke

```
getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
```

In the code above, change the alpha transparency value of 100 in order to find the suitable darkness.

---

> ..wan't the JFrame to go back to normal after the new window is closed. I tried setVisible(false) but it didn't work.

It works in this example.

[image: Shadowed Frame]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ShadowedFrame extends JFrame {

    ShadowedFrame() {
        super("Shadowed Frame");
        getRootPane().setGlassPane(new JComponent() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                super.paintComponent(g);
            }
        });
        JButton popDialog = new JButton("Block Frame");
        popDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ShadowedFrame.this, "Shady!");
                getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        setContentPane(popDialog);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setSize(350,180);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ShadowedFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine, but i wan't the JFrame to go back to normal after the new window is closed. I tried `setVisible(false)` but it didn't work.

Comment: This works just as i wanted it! thanks. is it possible to make the JDialog an external class, i want to have some options in it, like choose color of the frame in the dialogbox?

Comment: Or more lite, can `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ShadowedFrame.this, "Shady!");` be a reference to another class, which extends a JDialog?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The glass pane implementation has no children, so overriding `paintComponent` and `paint` is the same. But you're right, to set a good example it should be `paintComponent`. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Handsken yes, you can show any modal dialog derived from `JDialog` instead of showing the `JOptionPane`.

Comment: *"is it possible to.."*  LOL! Most things are *possible,* but this is an **SSCCE,** where 'anything goes' - and how many other ways can you get a modal dialog (as used by `JOptionPane`) on-screen in just one line of code? ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson the newest problem i had was that i have to much info that i want to display in a "pop-up" that to just add it in one line `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ShadowedFrame.this, "All my info here");` . so i wonder if i could do like - `getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(true);`
                `Class c = new Class();`
               `getRootPane().getGlassPane().setVisible(false);` Cause i can't get it to work?

Comment: @Handsken  Can't you?  In any case it sounds like a separate question, one on which you should post your own [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of (broken) code.  It does not have to be as short as the one I posted, but trim out anything that is not necessary to see it break.  Oh, and we probably won't need any screenshots, as pretty as they were.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson No sorry for a fussy question, i can open a new class(window) but when i close it the frame wont setvisible(false) on the black screen. So.. Having a Jdialog in another class, opening it, the JFrame becomes black, closing the Dialog, the screen is still black, but it works if the dialog is in the same class, as your example. so its not a error, its just something im doing wrong :P

Answer (score 4):

(Untested, but..) Seems like a good task for a `JLayeredPane`.  Create a `JComponent` that is set transparent and add that to the top level of the layered pane.  In the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of the component, set a semi-transparent color and fill the full area with it.  In normal use (non-dimmed), call `customComponent.setVisible(false)`.

### Update

Or, as Ingo pointed out, use the glass pane.

> I'm guessing its a `JWindow` that appears and the `JFrame` becomes unselectable in the background

It is more likely a modal [`JDialog`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).  When a modal dialog is visible, the frame/window that is the owner becomes inaccessible (cannot be clicked on).

Comment: Thanks! I switched my JWindows to JDialogs, worked much better! :)